# Force every HTTPS to one url

Tags: iptables, routing, redirect, https, filter

Is there a bug free way to redirect/forward all HTTPS requests which forwarding through a router to one url ?
I want to redirect all clients https to specific page something like hotspots walled garden .
I know that https is secure and we can not see inside of it . i want to redirect every https and there is no if/then statements in packet flow so maybe it will possible

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, not without every browser giving huge red "certificate mismatch" alerts.